# Inserting large blob (bigger than memory) to SQLite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, blob

Please do not bother asking why I am wanting to write a 13GB (or more) file to the database - its just the nature of the beast that I have to do this.

My problem is I think its loading it all into memory and I dont want to do that, I need to stream it into the blob either in chunks or on-the-fly using as little memory as possible.

here is the code I currently have:

```
Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(InPutFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read)
    Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(fs)
        Dim data(fs.Length - 1) As Byte
        fs.Read(data, 0, fs.Length)
        Using cmd As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand(TSQLDB)
            data = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(InPutFile)
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [FileSpace] SET [FileData]=@DAT WHERE [ID]=" & MyID
            cmd.Prepare()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DAT", DbType.Binary, fs.Length)
            cmd.Parameters("@DAT").Value = data
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
        End Using
        data = Nothing
    End Using
End Using
```

Any help would be most appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: Could you make a stored procedure that takes a chunk and appends it to the data already stored in that field?

Comment: Use the [SQLiteBlob object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041820/error-retrieving-blob-field-using-system-data-sqlite-sqlitedatareader-getblob). Please note that this cannot change the size of a blob; create the blob value first with [zeroblob()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#zeroblob).

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be limits to SQLite - just looking on the sqlite.org website, blobs are limited to 2147483647 bytes, which only equates to approx 2GB. There is a command I have found: SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH

I think the only other way around this is going to be for me to insert this is to split up the file into 2GB chunks and insert them that way, then re-join the blobs into one file when saving. Nothing is ever easy! - thanks for the comments though - it gave me food for thought and got me to find this possible resolution.